# Isolate methods with same name based on type using AspectJ?

Tags: java, aspectj

Say I have a pointcut on the `run()` method.

```
pointcut run(): execution(public void *.run());
before(): run() {
    // do something with run
}
```

But I only want to catch some instances of run. For example:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // this run should be intercepted
    }
});

new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // this run should be ignored
    }
}, 0, 1000);
```

How can I change my pointcut to forget about the `run()` that's not from a Thread?

Comment: You can easily distinguish between the `run` method of anonymous `Runnable` instances and anonymous `TimerTask` instances, but differentiating between how the resulting object instance is used would be much more difficult, if possible at all, withing reasonable efforts.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete thks for the help! It was actually a pretty trivial question, should have sentenced it better.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete what is the first is a `new Thread(new Runnable` and the second a `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable` how would you filter the Executor one?

Comment: To advise code based on the usage context of advised objects is not really feasible with AspectJ. I'm not saying it cannot be done (it's a super-set of Java after all), but AspectJ is not designed for this particular use case. I mean, you would like to branch based on what will happen with the `Runnable` instance after creation. In reality, anything could happen with that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to advise all implementations of the `Runnable.run()` method except where the class providing the implementation of that run method is a subclass of `TimerTask`, it can be done efficiently with the following pointcut expression:

```
execution(public void Runnable+.run()) && !execution(public void java.util.TimerTask+.run());
```

Comment: This is so much better than my answer. Many thanks. Not going to delete mine as there is value in seeing non-ideal ways of doing stuff but gonna point here.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** while the code bellow works do check [Nándor Előd Fekete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2699901/n%C3%A1ndor-el%C5%91d-fekete) accepted answer as it's much more efficient.

From [AspectJ Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596006543) was pretty easy to infer the solution:

```
pointcut run(): execution(public void *.run()) && !target(java.util.TimerTask);
before(): run() {
    // do something with run, will not catch instances of TimerTask
}
```

Comment: This can be done in a more efficient way with AspectJ. If this is what you intend to do, I can formulate an answer to your question.

Comment: The `target(java.util.TimerTask)` pointcut subexpression works, but it involves a runtime test. That means, that, in the above form of your pointcut expression, aspectj will advise all `void run()` methods in all classes in your codebase, and put a runtime test in all those places to filter where the target of the method execution is a `TimerTask` instance. The same thing can be achieved more efficiently with a more specific pointcut expression that doesn't involve runtime tests, as shown in my answer.